# How can I replace all instances of a match with itself and more? Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, regex

Ok, so say I have a bunch of `input`s in an HTML file like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ogwb">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="aosgh">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="aghw">
```

How can I replace all instances of the `id`s with themselves and a `name` and `value` attribute having the same `id` value like so:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ogwb" name="ogwb" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['ogwb']); ?>">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="aosgh" name="aosgh" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['aosgh']); ?>">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="aghw" name="aghw" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['aghw']); ?>">
```

This is what I've tried:

```
f = File.read('my.html')
$arr = f.scan(/id="([^"]*)"/)

$arr.each{ |a|
    e_ = a.join(", ")+'"'
    e__ = a.join(", ")+'"'+' name="'+a.join(", ")+'" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['+"'"+a.join(", ")+"'"+']); ?>"'
    f.gsub(/#{e_}/,e__)
}
```

Which if I do `puts e_` and `puts e__` I get the match and replace I want, but `gsub` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Use something like [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) instead

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use regex to grab this:

```regex
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="([^"]+)">
```

Notice that I surrounded the text value of the id with a capturing group (the brackets). This is capture group #1.

You can access the first captured group with `\1`.

So you'll want to **search** for the previous regex, and **replace** it with the following:

```regex
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="\1" name="\1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['\1']); ?>">
```

Demonstration: https://regex101.com/r/qeHkmg/1

Documentation: http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html

Comment: Make sure you escape the ``\``'s with more ``\``'s when using gsub.